# How to fill a listview using Kotlin, retrofit and RXjava

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2

My integration with the service is ready, I can see my array in the requisition log, but I can not fill the listview.

I honestly already tried everything I know, I'm new with kotlin the language makes me a little confused. Someone could identify where the error might be, which I'm doing wrong.

json/request:

```
{"0":{"id":1,"nome":"teste"},"1":{"id":2,"nome":"teste 2"}}
```

apiClient.kt

```
 val service : ApiInterface
    val URL = "json"

    init {

        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)

        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build()

        service = retrofit.create<ApiInterface>(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
```

ApiInterface.kt

```
 @Headers("Accept: application/json")
 @GET("/request")
 fun getInstituicoes(): Observable<Instituicao>
```

Instituicao.kt (entity)

```
 data class Instituicao(val id: Int, val nome: String)
```

InstituicaoActivity::listview

```
   listView = ListView(this)
        setContentView(listView)
        instituicao = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, instituicoes)
        listView?.adapter = instituicao

        var api = ApiClient()
        api.service.getInstituicoes()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    instituicao -> instituicoes.add("${instituicao.id} - ${instituicao.nome}")
                }, {
                    e -> e.printStackTrace()
                }, {
                    instituicao?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                })

    }
```

result :(

```
0-null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Object is this

```
{"0":
     {"id":1,"nome":"teste"}
```

Gson expected to parse only this piece as one Object

```
{"id":1,"nome":"teste"}
```

Since it could not, it has returned null.

If possible, you need to fix the server code to return you a list of objects, not an "indexed map"

The server response should be

```
[
   {"id":1,"nome":"teste"},
   {"id":2,"nome":"teste 2"}
]
```

After you fix the server to return that, Retrofit needs to be updated with this

```
Observable<List<Instituicao>>
```

And if that's not possible, you'll need to research about making custom parsers for Gson and register them in Retrofit

(... or parse your JSON manually)

Comment: I will try this;